# Next js GET request and download csv from Flask

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, flask, next.js

I have trouble that I have already succeeded in downloading CSV from Flask (localhost5000). And I type localhost5000/download, the file can be downloaded successfully.

However, when I use Next Js to fetch the URL, this shows error "Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data"  ---It is response.json().

After that, I use response.text(). The data can be fetched and show the data in my console but I need to download CSV.

Could someone help me to solve this problem?

Here is my Nextjs code

```
import React from "react";
import Layout from "@/components/Layout";
import { API_URL } from "../config";
export default function adminpage() {
  const downloadCSV = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const response = await fetch(`${API_URL}/download`, {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
    });
    const data = await response.text();
    console.log(data);
  };

  return (
    <Layout>
      <h1>Here is admin page</h1>
      <button onClick={downloadCSV}>Download report (CSV)</button>
    </Layout>
  );
}
```

And here is my flask code

```
@app.route("/download", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def download():
    file_data = Applicant.query.all()

    
    with open('output.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
        # Use CSV writer module
        writer = csv.writer(csvfile)

        # Write first row (Header)
        writer.writerow(["Id", "FirstName", "LastName"])

        # Write all information from Sqlite db
        for i in file_data:
            writer.writerow([i.id, i.firstName, i.lastName])

        
    return flask.send_file('output.csv', as_attachment=True)
```

---

Finally, I found this code which fit for my purpose. Here is the Next JS frontend code.

```
import React from "react";
import Layout from "@/components/Layout";
import { API_URL } from "../config";
export default function adminpage() {
  const downloadCSV = async (e) => {
    // Prevent Form submit, the form will refresh too fast and can't be sent the data to backend database if no prevent default
    e.preventDefault();
    const response = await fetch(`${API_URL}/download`, {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
    });
    const data = await response.blob();

    // Create a blob with the data we want to download as a file
    //  ***Need to change {type: "jpg/mp3/csv or other"}
    const blob = new Blob([data], { type: "csv" });
    // Create an anchor element and dispatch a click event on it
    // to trigger a download
    const a = document.createElement("a");
    //  ***Need to change "output.csv" => This is a file name can be changed
    a.download = "output.csv";
    a.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    const clickEvt = new MouseEvent("click", {
      view: window,
      bubbles: true,
      cancelable: true,
    });
    a.dispatchEvent(clickEvt);
    a.remove();
  };

  return (
    <Layout>
      <h1>Here is admin page</h1>
      <button onClick={downloadCSV}>Download report (CSV)</button>
    </Layout>
  );
}
```

Comment: When downloading CSV files your `Content-Type` header should be set to `"text/csv"`.